# Diff for Redis between two databases

Tags: redis

What is the best way to see differences between the contents of two different Redis databases? We have a development and production deployment and our production instance doesn't seem to have the same exact data as development but we need a solid easy way to test that - is there a good way to do this without writing too much of our own code?

Comment: You could do Keys * then save the outcome to a file and perform diff on it.

Comment: Each database is on a different redis server?

Comment: No, @BasitAnwer  don't ever recommend using the `keys` command on production servers. Especially when it wouldn't actually answer the question given. all that would do is tell you if they had the same key names, not if or what *data* differs.

Comment: @IoniţăCosmin, in our case we are talking about 2 different Redis Sentinel instances at different IPs, but we are only talking about the data in database=0 for each instance, we aren't worried about the other 15 "databases" in Redis.

Comment: @TheRealBill Yes you're right, what the heck was i thinking :/

Answer (score 4):

If your production data has a high rate of change, doing this would be tough. So for this answer let us assume you either don't have a high data churn or you can do this at a quiescent time where the data churn rate is low.

For this to work from a shell script perspective you will need to do the first task in parallel.

1. Use the RDB save option in redis-cli to pull down a local copy of the data for each server.
2. Compare a hash of the files, such as an md5sum. If they are the same, the data is the same.

If the churn rate is low enough that you can get a comparable dump, this will identify if they are different, but not what data differs if any. However you can use this as a conditional for avoiding a deeper dive which has to essentially ransack the database.

Alternatively, if they differ you could write something which uses the RDB files and one of the RDB file parsers to compare them and output the differences it finds.

Indeed this method would work far better than ransacking the server as data can change during the process whereas the dump file analysis method compares for a fixed point in time.

Answer (score 0):

Because we are using Redis Sentinel I assumed I couldn't find some code to steal, so wrote my own real quick

the code compares the contents of two different Redis databases, using the `ioredis` Redis client NPM module. The code works fine for small Redis databases that don't change much, for larger amounts of data or for databases that are seeing a lot of writes per minute, this might not be suitable.

code looks like this:

```
var async = require('async');

var Redis = require('ioredis');


var REDIS_SENTINEL_MASTER_NAME_STAGING = 'smartconndevredis01';
var REDIS_SENTINEL_MASTER_NAME_PROD = 'smartconnect_curr_master';

var SENTINEL_ENDPOINTS_STAGING = [
    {
        "host": "XXX.XX.XX.XX",
        "port": "26379"
    },
    {
        "host": "XXX.XX.X.XX",
        "port": "26379"
    },
    {
        "host": "XXX.XX.X.XX",
        "port": "26379"
    }
];


var SENTINEL_ENDPOINTS_PROD = [
    {
        "host": "XXX.XX.X.XX",
        "port": "26379"
    },
    {
        "host": "XXX.XX.X.XX",
        "port": "26379"
    },
    {
        "host": "XXX.X.XX.XX",
        "port": "26379"
    }
];


var clientStaging = new Redis({
    sentinels: SENTINEL_ENDPOINTS_STAGING,
    name: REDIS_SENTINEL_MASTER_NAME_STAGING,
    db: 0
});


var clientProd = new Redis({
    sentinels: SENTINEL_ENDPOINTS_PROD,
    name: REDIS_SENTINEL_MASTER_NAME_PROD,
    db: 0
});


var dbStaging = {};
var dbProd = {};


async.parallel([

        function (callback) {
            clientStaging.keys('*', function (err, keys) {

                async.each(keys, function (key, cb) {

                    clientStaging.get(key, function (err, result) {
                        //console.log('staging> key: "'+key+'", result:', result);
                        dbStaging[key] = result;
                        cb(err);
                    });

                }, function done(err, res) {
                    callback(err, res);
                });
            });

        },
        function (callback) {
            clientProd.keys('*', function (err, keys) {

                async.each(keys, function (key, cb) {

                    clientProd.get(key, function (err, result) {
                        //console.log('production> key: "'+key+'", result:', result);
                        dbProd[key] = result;
                        cb(err);
                    });

                }, function done(err, res) {
                    callback(err, res);
                });
            });

        }
    ],
    function done(err, results) {

        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        else {
            diffDbs();
        }

    });


function diffDbs() {

    Object.keys(dbStaging).forEach(function (key) {

        if (!dbProd.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            console.log('staging redis has key, prod redis does not:',key);
        }
        else {

            var stagingVal = dbStaging[key];
            var prodVal = dbProd[key];

            if(String(stagingVal).valueOf() != String(prodVal).valueOf()){
                console.log('staging redis and prod redis have DIFFERENT values for key:',key);
            }
        }

    });

    Object.keys(dbProd).forEach(function (key) {

        if (!dbStaging.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            console.log('prod redis has key, staging redis does not:',key);
        }
        else {

            var stagingVal = String(dbStaging[key]).replace(/ /g, ''); //remove all whitespace
            var prodVal = String(dbProd[key]).replace(/ /g, ''); //remove all whitespace

            if(stagingVal.valueOf() != prodVal.valueOf()){
                console.log('staging redis and prod redis have DIFFERENT values for key:',key);
            }
        }
    });

    process.exit(0);

}
```

Comment: As a general tip I'd recommend using the same pod name in staging as in prod since you have  sentinel constellations dedicated to each environment.  That way sentinel using code doesn't have to be award which environment it is in. And for your code, don't use keys. Use scan. This will destroy performance on a busy server with a lot of keys as it is algorithmicly  complex and blocking. Fine for staging, not for prod.

Comment: thanks, yeah, our Redis instances are small, less than 1 mb each, and aren't experience a lot of writes - I agree it makes perfect sense to find a way to get a snapshot of the database in order to do a fair comparison. Like you say it might make sense to do an evented dump of both DBs, and then compare those two different dump.rdb files.

Comment: but I didn't know what you meant by "pod" name, do you mean "master_name"? you are probably referring to these being different: var REDIS_SENTINEL_MASTER_NAME_STAGING = 'smartconndevredis01';
var REDIS_SENTINEL_MASTER_NAME_PROD = 'smartconnect_curr_master';

Comment: Yes, pod name is the name you give to the master-slave setup when adding it to sentinel via the `sentinel monitor` command.